# Letter D on dashboard

Tags: honda, crv, dashboard

There is a letter D above my MPH ON MY 2017 HONDA CRV. Never noticed it before and I can't find anything about it in the manual

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could I have you take a picture of exactly what you're talking about? Make sure the "D" I'm thinking of is the D you're talking about :o)

Comment: It is not by any chance the "D" for "Drive", the setting of your automatic transmission? That would be a bit obvious but still...

Answer (score 3):

According to page 11 and 12 of the [owner manual](http://techinfo.honda.com/rjanisis/pubs/OM/AH/ATLA1717OM/enu/ATLA1717OM.PDF), there are two available gauge configurations.

The one you described has the **Shift Lever Position Indicator** above the speedometer.

[image]

There is another gauge cluster style, but it has the **Shift Lever Position Indicator** to the left of the speedometer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the letter to the *left* of the MPH readout, is the current position of the transmission (Park, Neutral, Drive, etc.)

[image]

Is that what you are referring to?